# Identify 2017 Bag #2? Cash register and “I love HLC” stickers

Tags: set-identification

Can anyone help identify this Friends set? Bag #2 has 2017 copyright with “511R8” on bag. Cash register and “I love HLC” stickers in set.

Comment: A photo would be ever so helpful if you could post one. I've taken a stab at it, but the set I found doesn't have a cash register. Almost all sticker sheets nowadays will have a long (like 8-digit) code on them, which will make identification **super** reliable.

Comment: The numbers on the bag concern the bag itself, not the set it was in, so that is worthless. "HLC" in "I love HLC" probably means "HeartLake City", placing the set in the Friends-theme - they have a lot of pieces/stickers with that text, there are also several shops with cash registers there. To be more precise I second RSchulz's request for a photo.

Answer (score 3):

[image: 87552pb049]

Is it this piece? That is [87552pb049](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=87552pb049) and only shows up in [10763](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=10763-1) Stephanie's Lakeside House [image: 10763]

[image: tile]

This piece isn't a sticker, but shows up in multiple sets that have a cash register.